# Unsupervised Convolutional Autoencoder is always giving blank output

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to train an autoencoder with unsupervised images. I have about 300 train images and 100 validation images. But when I inputted an unseen image to the trained autoencoder, it is giving complete blank output.

```
train_images = os.listdir('./Data/train')
val_images = os.listdir('./Data/val')

X_train = []
X_val = []

for i in range(len(train_images)):
    img = cv2.imread('./Data/train/'+train_images[i])
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    X_train.append(resized)

X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')/255.
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train), 224, 224, 1))

for i in range(len(val_images)):
    img = cv2.imread('./Data/val/'+val_images[i])
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    X_val.append(resized)

X_val = np.asarray(X_val)
X_val = X_val.astype('float32')/255.
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (len(X_val), 224, 224, 1))

print(len(X_train))
print(len(X_val))
```

Here `X_train.shape` and `X_val.shape` respectively are `(300,224,224,1)` and `(100, 224, 224, 1)`

here is my `upconv_concat` function

```
def upconv_concat(bottom_a, bottom_b, n_filter, pool_size, stride, padding='VALID'):
    up_conv = Conv2DTranspose(filters=n_filter, kernel_size=[pool_size, pool_size],
                                         strides=stride, padding=padding)(bottom_a)
    return Concatenate(axis=-1)([up_conv, bottom_b])
```

here are some parameters

```
input_img = Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))
droprate=0.25
num_classes = 1
```

and here is my model

```
conv_1_1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
conv_1_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_1_1)
conv_1_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_1_1_bn)

pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= 2, strides = 2)(conv_1_1_do)

conv_4_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_1)
conv_4_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_4_1)
conv_4_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_4_1_bn)

pool_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= 2, strides = 2)(conv_4_1_do)

conv_5_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 1024, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_4)
conv_5_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_5_1)
conv_5_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_5_1_bn)

upconv_1 = upconv_concat(conv_5_1_do, conv_4_1_do, n_filter=512, pool_size=2, stride=2) 

conv_6_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upconv_1)
conv_6_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_6_1)
conv_6_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_6_1_bn)


upconv_2 = upconv_concat(conv_6_1_do, conv_1_1_do, n_filter=64, pool_size=2, stride=2) 

conv_9_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upconv_2)
conv_9_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_9_1)
conv_9_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_9_1_bn)


ae_output = Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=1, strides = (1,1), activation="softmax")(conv_9_1_do)
```

here is the training part

```
ae_model = Model(input_img, ae_output)
ae_model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
ae_model.fit(X_train, X_train,
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=16,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(X_val, X_val))
```

if anyone needs the model summary

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 64) 640         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 224, 224, 64) 256         conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 224, 224, 64) 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
separable_conv2d_1 (SeparableCo (None, 112, 112, 512 33856       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 112, 112, 512 2048        separable_conv2d_1[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 112, 112, 512 0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 512)  0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
separable_conv2d_2 (SeparableCo (None, 56, 56, 1024) 529920      max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 56, 56, 1024) 4096        separable_conv2d_2[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 56, 56, 1024) 0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 112, 112, 512 2097664     dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 112, 112, 102 0           conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
separable_conv2d_3 (SeparableCo (None, 112, 112, 512 534016      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 112, 112, 512 2048        separable_conv2d_3[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 112, 112, 512 0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 224, 224, 64) 131136      dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 224, 224, 128 0           conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
separable_conv2d_4 (SeparableCo (None, 224, 224, 64) 9408        concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 224, 224, 64) 256         separable_conv2d_4[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 224, 224, 64) 0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 1)  65          dropout_5[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 3,345,409
Trainable params: 3,341,057
Non-trainable params: 4,352
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I have absolutely checked the X_train images to see if I am sending blank images by mistake. But no. I'm sending proper data only.

**The problem is**

when I tried to test the model, it is giving a blank image.

```
img = cv2.imread('./test/a184.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized = cv2.resize(img, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized = resized/255
resized = resized[:, :, np.newaxis]
resized = resized[np.newaxis, :, :]
```

now `resized` is of shape `(1,224,224,1)`

```
image = ae_model.predict(resized)
image = image.reshape((224,224))

plt.imshow(image, cmap= 'gray')
```

gives me this image:
[image]
but the values in `image` variable are all 1s.

I'm using tf.Keras.

Please help me with this. Unable to locate where the problem is and how to debug to find it.

Comment: The bug is due to copy-pasta. If you had a single function that did image preprocessing instead of having multiple copies of the code, one of them buggy, you wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Did not work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black image comes from the way you are activating your last conv layer.
Here you want to predict, for each pixel, a value between 0 and 1, so you need a Sigmoid activation, not a Softmax one.

Try with this instead :

```
ae_output = Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=1, strides = (1,1), activation="sigmoid")(conv_9_1_do)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm now able to see the reconstructed image. Any idea on how to use this as a segmentation model, like predicting the probability of each pixel being 0, 1, 2 (3 classes)? More of a semantic segmentation problem. That is the reason I had put a softmax layer over there. I introduced a variable `num_classes` for this purpose, but I'm a bit unsure about how to include that in the model.

Comment: I never implemented segmentation models, so i can't really help you on that point sorry :/